# How to get all browser cookies?

Tags: javascript, cookies

All Hello! Please tell me how to get all the cookies of the browser, which is currently in the cache?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can olny access cookies for your domain by using `document.cookie`

Comment: Have you tried this on your own at all? What did you try? Why didn't it work, or why doesn't it meet your requirements?

Comment: I feel like I just want to come out and say that, while in most cases a question barely over 20 words long is almost always a poorly constructed question, and in desparate need of down-voting, I don't think this particular question needs down-voting. I guess it could have been lengthened but look at the high-quality (and equally as brief) answer that was able to come out of it. If the question were this bad, that wouldn't be possible. I will say, however, that it doesn't seem that much research was done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get cookies for the domain/path you're on, *JavaScript* provides [`document.cookie`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.cookie), which returns a *String* which is a semicolon-seperated `;` list of cookies.

Comment: … except for cookies marked HTTP Only.

Comment: and in chrome for urls using the "file://" protocol, if not launched with the "--enable-file-cookies" flag

Comment: If you want to learn more about _HTTP Only_ cookies, I found a decent article [**here**](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/05/05/http-cookies-explained/), see section labeled **HTTP-Only cookies**.

Comment: thank you, colleagues...